# How can I use XPath to get elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath

My XML is like:

```
<root>
  <section name="blah">
    <item name="asdf">2222</item>
  </section>
</root>
```

I will have multiple 'sections' in the XML, I want to fetch a particular section.

In this case, I need to get items that are in the section named "blah".

Comment: btw, your xml is malformed (missing </section>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xpath is then:

```
/root/section[@name='blah']/item
```

for example, in `XmlDocument`:

```
foreach(XmlElement item in doc.SelectNodes("/root/section[@name='blah']/item"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("name"));
     Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

---

Edit re comments: if you just want the sections, then use:

```
/root/section[@name='blah']
```

but then you'll need to iterate the data manually (since you can theoretically have multiple sections named "blah", each of which can have multiple items).

Comment: wouldn't it be doc.SelectNodes("/root/section[@name='blah']") ??

Comment: @Blankman: Not as long as you are interested in the *items* that are child of such a section.

Comment: indeed: <quote>get items that have a section name "blah".</quote>

Comment: no that would only return collection of sections. you said you wanted to get access to a collection of items that are children of that particular section.

Comment: What I am doing is iterating through all the item nodes and loading them into a dictionary (name/value pairs).  So I just need a collection of all the items.